# Самостоятельная сборка программы

Tags: c, компиляция, include, сборка

Доброго времени суток. Захотел разобраться в работе JohnTheRipper, а именно, в работе модуля HMAC_SHA256. Нашёл исходники https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/tree/bleeding-jumbo/src, файл - `hmacSHA256_fmt_plug.c`. Так вот. Создаю в VS12 пустой проект, в папку `файлы исходного кода` вставляю данный файл и начинаю потихоньку добавлять недостающие хедеры. Проблема почти сразу возникла с `arch.h`, которого почему-то не оказалось среди файлов в исходниках. 
Загуглил и нашёл следующий файл на https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/objtool/arch.h. Но не уверен, то ли это (смутили linux-хедеры). Не подскажите, в чём дело? Если дело в том, что в Windows нет `arch.h`, то можно ли чем-то заменить данный файл?

Comment: Если вам нужно разобраться с HMAC - берите лучше OpenSSL, там вроде есть нужный алгоритм и она точно собирается под вендой, да еще и Студией.

Comment: Да-да, я об знаю, но мне необходим именно JohnTheRipper. Да и интересно стало, как разрешить мою проблему.

Comment: `arch.h` на самом деле ссылка. Которая создастся в момент конфигурации.

Comment: @retorta, то есть на винде я вряд ли смогу скомпилировать данный код?

Comment: @Setplus не вижу концептуальных проблем в этом.

Comment: @retorta, поясните, пожалуйста, что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Попробуйте скомпилировать без этого файла. посмотрите каких типов данных не хватит и объявите их. Судя по названию в arch.h должны объявляться типы, зависимые от платформы. И этот файл обычно генерится при сборке всего проекта целиком некими скриптами из него, вам надо выполнить работу за эти скрипты вручную

Comment: @Mike, хорошо, спасибо за совет. Тогда я просто пока что удалю данное включение и без него постараюсь скомпилировать код.